# bootstrap overlapping columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i took the template from:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_temp_webpage&stacked=h

and my final program became: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FM4QTOQ319HP

i don't understand why my columns overlap when i resize my window before turning to xs where they get stacked. They overlap for quite some while till i turn my windows small enough to get to xs resolution. can anyone help me in here. i tried other solutions on this site but none seemed to help. i have all my columns add up to 12 and div max width is 100%

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @SyedSarek the code is too long and even a minimum working example would be too long.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set width 100% of Master div and remove other div's width.